# Expo - Access to all photos is required to do this operation

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an application built with expo and when a user download a picture on iOS, I'm getting this error on bugsnag:

> Access to all photos is required to do this operation.

I'm not myself an iPhone user. I could replicate this with someone else iPhone, got the error but nothing apparent on the iPhone's user.

I realized later that I forgot to add this to **app.config.json**

```json
export default {
  ...
  "plugins": [
    [
      "expo-media-library",
      {
        "photosPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your photos.",
        "savePhotosPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to save photos."
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

After adding it, it seems to have fixed the issue on the testflight (probably because the user had to uninstall-reinstall the app).
However, after deploying the app in the store, the error keeps happening. I suppose it should have re-asking for permissions ? *(If so, I have no idea how)*

Here's how I register the permissions and download the picture

```js
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import logger from '~application/utility/logger';

const albumName = "MyApplicationName";

const download = async (uri, fileName, headers, callback) => {
    registerLibraryPermissions()
        .then((granted) => granted ? downloadFile(uri, fileName, headers, callback) : null)
};

const downloadFile = async (uri, fileName, headers, callback) => {
    if (Object.keys(headers).length === 0) return null;
    try {
        return FileSystem.createDownloadResumable(uri, FileSystem.documentDirectory + fileName, {headers: headers}, callback)
            .downloadAsync()
            .then(({uri}) => moveToGallery(uri))
            .catch(error => logger.log("Error downloading the file", error));
    } catch (error) {
        logger.log("Error while downloading the photo", error)
    }
}

const moveToGallery = async (localUri) => {
    try {
        const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(localUri);
        return await MediaLibrary.getAlbumAsync(albumName).then(album => {
            if (album !== null) {
                return MediaLibrary.addAssetsToAlbumAsync([asset], album, false)
                    .catch((error) => logger.log('Error while adding photo', error));
            }

            return MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync(albumName, asset, false)
                .catch((error) => logger.log('Error while saving photo', error));
        });

    } catch (error) {
        logger.log('Error while saving photo', error)
    }

}

const registerLibraryPermissions = async () => {
    try {
        const {status: existingStatus} = await MediaLibrary.getPermissionsAsync();
        let finalStatus = existingStatus;

        if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
            const {status} = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
            finalStatus = status;
        }

        if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
            alert("L'accès à la média libairie n'a pas pu être activé sur votre téléphone");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        logger.log('Error getting the permissions for media library', error);
    }
};

export default {
    download,
};
```

[image]

Am I missing something? Thanks